# Many-To-Many Relationship within a table in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel for the first time. I have a scenario where I have a **Products** table which contains all the details of a Product (Corrugated Box) like length, breadth, height etc. Few products have a **Parent** part and many **Child** parts which constitute to become the complete product. Both Parent and the Child parts have exactly the same properties (i.e. length, breadth, height etc) and every Child part can and has to be treated as an individual product as per the requirement. And, I also have to record as to how many Child parts are necessary for every Parent part to get the finished product.

Ex: 1 Parent part + 2 Child parts_1 + 1 Child parts_2 = 1 Finished Product.

To be more specific: 1 Master Carton + 2 Pads + 3 Partitions = 1 Box.

I have created a model **Product** and a migration **products** like this:

```
php artisan make:model Product -m
```

Migration looks like this:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('product_code');
        $table->integer('part_type_id');
        $table->integer('box_type_id');
        $table->float('length');
        $table->float('breadth');
        $table->float('height');
        $table->float('ply');
        $table->float('gsm_a_base');
        $table->float('gsm_a_flute');
        $table->float('gsm_b_base');
        $table->float('gsm_b_flute');
        $table->float('gsm_top');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Now I have to create a table which holds the details like

**| parent_product_id | child_product_id | qty_of_child_per_parent |**

where **parent_product_id** and **child_product_id** are foreign keys of the **id** field in **products** table. Please help me achieve this relationship or let me know if there's a better way of doing it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you'd create a new table with the columns you stated (let's name this table parent_child_products), you should be able to add relation functions to your model:

```
public function childProducts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'parent_child_products', 'child_product_id', 'parent_product_id')->withPivot('qty_of_child_per_parent');
}
public function parentProducts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'parent_child_products', 'child_product_id', 'parent_product_id')->withPivot('qty_of_child_per_parent');
}
```

By adding the withPivot() part, the quantity column will be added on the pivot object of the related item, which you can access like this:

```
$sumOfChildren = 0;
foreach($product->childProducts as $childProduct) {
    $sumOfChildren += $childProduct->pivot->qty_of_child_per_parent;
}
```